# jQuery mouseleave e.toElement || e.relatedTarget won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a user hover card like on Facebook. But I have a problem with the following code:

```
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.avatar', function(e) {
    var to = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget;
      if (!$(to).is(".card")) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.card').remove();
        }, 1000);
      }
  });
```

The jQuery code must be working like: *if not* `to = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget` *then* remove the `.card` div. But if you mouseleave the black div (`.card`) it should stay on there, not `remove()`.

Can anyone help me here ?

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/gjzPwL)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("mouseenter", ".avatar", function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var posY = offset.top - $(window).scrollTop() + $(this).height();
    var posX = offset.left - $(window).scrollLeft();
    var available = $(window).width() - posX;
    if ($(window).width() > 800) {
        
          $("body").append('<div class="card" style="position: fixed; top: ' + posY + 'px; left:' + posX + 'px"></div>');
       
    }
  });
  $('body').on('mouseleave', '.avatar', function(e) {
    var to = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget;
      if (!$(to).is(".card")) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('.card').remove();
        }, 1000);
      }
  });
  $('body').on('mouseleave', '.card', function() {
    $('.card').remove();
  });
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  max-width:660px;
  margin:0px auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-top:100px;
}
.post {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
.avatar {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  position:realtive;
  border-radius:50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.avatar img {
  width:160%;
}

.card {
  width:300px;
  padding:100px 0px;
  background-color:#000000;
  border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="avatar" id="1"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/56866/garden-rose-red-pink-56866.jpeg"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="avatar" id="2"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/56866/garden-rose-red-pink-56866.jpeg"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="avatar" id="3"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/56866/garden-rose-red-pink-56866.jpeg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this)` is not working for you?

Comment: @Jai no this `var to = e.toElement || e.relatedTarget;` not working.

Comment: `var to = $(this);` try this.

Comment: @Jai Same not fixed

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

## JS

Add a cover div to make it fill from the avatar "Y coord".

```
$("body").append('<div class="cover_card" style="position: fixed; top: ' + posY + 'px; left:' + posX + 'px"><div class="card"></div></div>');
```

Modify the posY to reposition the cover from the avatar "Y coord".

```
posY = posY-50;
```

On mouse leave just remove the cover card container.

```
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.cover_card', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

## CSS

Modify css margin to adjust the posY change.

```
.card {
 width:300px;
  padding:100px 0px;
  background-color:#000000;
  border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
  margin-top:60px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejrZMJ

Answer (score -1):

Use this part of mouseleave, close card when mouse leave `.post`

```
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.post', function() {
    $('.card').remove();
});
```

And change this line in mouseenter, make `.card` part of `.post`

```
$(".post").append('<div class="card" style="position: fixed; top: ' + posY + 'px; left:' + posX + 'px"></div>');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this solution but. Card must be remove when `mosuleleave` `.avatar` and when `mouseleave` `.card`